# access denied "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm doing following tutorial where you implement a TensorFlow Lite model in an android app:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#0

Everything works well except that following error messages shows up while testing the app and my model doesn't recognize the images.

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
W/.classification: type=1400 audit(0.0:45214): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17052 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c88,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:persist_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
W/BpBinder: Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 213ms, interface=android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser, code=6 oneway=false
W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 0 at size 307200
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 1 at size 153599
    CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 2 at size 153599
W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
```

Has somebody experienced this issue before? I'm testing the app with a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro.